# MVC4: Using @Model in javascript inside @section in IIS6

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, iis-6

I am running my Asp.Net MVC 4 site on IIS6, and I have a Razor page which looks something like this

Layout file:

```
<div id="ltMainContent>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</div>
```

View file:

```
(some markup)

@section scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jsRazorFunc() {
        alert ("Razor inside script section works: " + @Model.Count  );
    };
    jsRazorFunc ();
</script>
}
```

That seems to break the Razor engine.

The page renders as:

```
<div="ltMainContent>
    (some markup)
    ;

    jsRazorFunc ();

    </script>
    }
</div>
```

This looks broken to me.

Some interesting observations:

- If I try this on IIS7, it works as expected
- If I take the code out of the @section, it works as expected
- If I remove the @Model and use a static text, it works as expected

Is this not supported in IIS6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Review these steps and make sure you have configured your app same way, you should be fine http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx